# I can't see the mistake im doing in laravel php Routes for api

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware

Im having problem with correct setting of api.php in Laravel, I can't seem to get the Routes with prefixes right. Here is the code for my routes, the problem is that I want to use middleware on first part of the route {token}, and right after that when I use return $next($request) in my middleware it has no response:

api.php :

```
Route::prefix('{token}')->middleware('token_verify')->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('services')->group(function () {
        Route::get("get/{id?}", [ServisController::class, 'getServices']);
        Route::post("set", [ServisController::class, 'setServices']);
        Route::delete("delete/{id}", [ServisController::class, 'deleteServices']);
    });
});
```

Kernel.php :

```
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\TokenMiddleware::class,
        ],
    ];
 protected $routeMiddleware = [

        'token_verify' => \App\Http\Middleware\TokenMiddleware::class,
        ....
];
```

TokenMiddleware.php :

```
 public function __construct(TokenService $tokenService)
    {
        $this->tokenService = $tokenService;
    }
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $token = $request->route('token');
        if ($this->tokenService->validToken($token) === false) {
            return new Response(['error' => 'Invalid token'], 401);
        }
        Log::error("next",["next" => $request->route()]);
        return $next($request);
    }
```

In TokenMiddleware everything is correct except last line `return $next($request);` from here it doesn't return any data.

I tried logging the route parameters but everything seems to be normal :
the Error log text :
`[2023-09-06 17:41:28] local.ERROR: next {"next":{"Illuminate\\Routing\\Route":{"uri":"api/{token}/orders/get/{id?}","methods":["GET","HEAD"],"action":{"middleware":["api"],"midleware":"token_verify","uses":"App\\Http\\Controllers\\ObjednavkyController@getObjednavky","controller":"App\\Http\\Controllers\\ObjednavkyController@getObjednavky","namespace":null,"where":[],"as":"generated::scJxnpmEXGgAWOXA","prefix":"api/{token}/orders"},"isFallback":false,"controller":[],"defaults":[],"wheres":[],"parameters":{"token":"xAdFOzuCBVM5O4gycQHSMJv73SH66x37RNv5c1ytoW6D5jVQ4WdJDCh8GWhvZ9jg"},"parameterNames":["token","id"],"computedMiddleware":["api"],"compiled":[]}}}`

postman scrrens
[image: with invalid token]
[image: with valid token]

What do I need to change for TokenMiddleware to work correctly and return data from verified route?
Thanks.

This is my ServisController, nothing special :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\servisy;
use Exception;
use Mockery\CountValidator\Exact;

class ServisController extends Controller
{
    function getServices($id = null)
    {
        return $id ? servisy::find($id) : servisy::all();
    }
    .....
]
```

Comment: Please add the `setServices` function from the `ServisController`

Comment: @benjah I added it to problem description right above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, I changed the token auth from passing it through dynamic url to passing it into request header. After this change everything started to work as it was supposed to.

Comment: Good on you for figuring it out!  

Both your question and your answer are greatly lacking details.  With your new-found expertise, maybe you could flesh both out for the benefit of others.

Thank you!